# How to connect Overtone through Light Table IDE

Tags: clojure, lighttable, overtone

I'm using Windows 7 64 bit, `light table 0.3.9`, and `lein 2.2.1`, but
I have problems connecting to Overtone from Light Table.

```
clojure.lang.Compiler$CompilerException:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: overtone.live
```

Answer (score 4):

Out of curiosity I installed `JDK 7` and `lein 2.1.2` on my Windows laptop and downloaded `light table 0.3.9`.

First, I created new lein project using `lein.bat new insane-noises` command.

Then, I opened light table ide and added `insane-noises` directory to the workspace.

Then, I edited my `project.clj` file to set right dependencies:

```
(defproject insane-noises "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :dependencies [ [org.clojure/clojure  "1.4.0"]
                  [overtone             "0.8.1"]])
```

Then, I edited my `core.clj` file:

```
(ns insane-noises.core
  (:use overtone.live))

(demo (sin-osc))
```

When I tried to eval `(demo (sin-osc))` line directly from light table editor, it downloaded all dependencies and played the noise.

Finally, I tried light table `instarepl`:

```
(use 'overtone.live)
(demo (sin-osc))
```

It played the same noise again.

So, I experienced no problems using overtone with light table ide from my x64 Windows 7.

Check your dependencies. Probably, you forgot to add `overtone` dependency to your `project.clj`.

Comment: thx for your answer, i didn't forget to add dependency to my project.clj,and I can not lanuch light table now.the interface doesn't appear on the screen.